# add more circles to my emananting animation in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I currently have an animation in which I am adding an emanating animation to each circle, but I have trouble adding more circles to each animation. I would like to have an effect like this:

[image]

http://plnkr.co/edit/aSKHmORNaAIKPfJLm0Ee?p=preview

In which there are several circles performing the animation of emananting animation infinite and never end. (thanks to @Mark)

This is my current code, in which I have created another instance of a circle, and for which I am trying to recreate this animated infinite animation of emanating in them with more circles. how can I do it?

[image]

```
    CircleNumber=Math.round(15)
    const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",250).attr("height",250);
    const data = Array.from(Array(CircleNumber).keys());
            var emanatingCircles=[];
    const radialGradient = svg.append("defs")
                              .append("radialGradient")
                              .attr("id", "radial-gradient");

    radialGradient.append("stop")
                      .attr("offset", "0%")
                      .attr("stop-color", "#f4425f");

    radialGradient.append("stop")
                    .attr("offset", "100%")
                    .attr("stop-color", "orange");
  for(var i=0; i<2; i++){

    // Outer 
    svg.append("circle")
       .classed('OuterCircle', true)
       .attr("id","fuera")
       .attr("cx",50*(i+2))
       .attr("cy",50*(i+2))
       .attr("r",10)
       .attr("fill","url(#radial-gradient)")
       .attr('gradient',()=>{return })
       .attr("stroke","orange")    
       .on('mouseover',function(d,i,g){
         console.log(g)
            d3.select(this).transition().ease("bounce").duration(500).attr("r",13)
         })
       .on('mouseout', function(d,i,g){
           d3.select(this).transition().ease("bounce").duration(500).attr("r",10)
         });
    // Inner
    svg.append('circle')
       .classed('InnerCircle',true)
       .attr('r',5)
       .attr("id","dentro")
       .attr('stroke','yellow')
       .attr('fill','yellow')
       .attr('opacity',1)
       .attr('cx',50*(i+2))
       .attr('cy',50*(i+2))
       .on('mouseover',function(d,i,g){
            console.log('outercircle');
            console.log(g[i]);
            d3.select(this).transition().ease("bounce").duration(500).attr("r",7)
         })
       .on('mouseout', function(d,i,g){
           d3.select(this).transition().ease("bounce").duration(500).attr("r",5)
         });

    emanatingCircles[i] = svg
      .append('circle')
      .attr('class','emanting')
      .attr('r',5)
      .attr('stroke','yellow')
      .attr('fill','none')
      .attr('opacity',1)
      .attr('stroke-width',2)
      .attr('cx',50*(i+2))
      .attr('cy',50*(i+2))


      emananting(i);

  }  


  function emananting(index) {
      console.log(index)
      emanatingCircles[index]
          .transition().duration(5000)
          .attr('opacity', 0)
          .attr('r', 20)
          .transition().duration(0)
          .attr('opacity', 0)
          .attr('r', 5)
          .each('end',()=>emananting(index)); // pass in a emananting function
      emanatingCircles[index].attr("opacity", 1);
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k4zugL7u/1/

thank you very much.

Comment: Instead of use the for loop, just use a data join to enter as many circles as you want?

Comment: @RyanMorton For me it's complicated, I had to choose this path because it did not work. maybe you can help me, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your entire `emananting` function can be written simply as:

```
function emananting() {
  var n = 0; // counter of how many transitions
  svg.selectAll('circle.emanting')
    .attr('r', 20) // set initial radius
    .style('opacity', 1) // and opacity
    .transition()
    .each(function() { ++n; }) // increment counter for each transition
    .duration((d, i) => {
      return 5000;
    })
    .delay((d, i) => {
      return i * 1000;
    })
    .attr('r', 50)
    .style('opacity', 0)
    .on("end", function() { 
       if (!--n) emananting(); // when all transitions end, restart emananting
    }); 
}
```

Running code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    /* On mouse hover, lighten state color */
    
    path:hover {
      fill-opacity: .7;
    }
    /* Style for Custom Tooltip */
    
    div.tooltip {
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      width: 60px;
      height: 28px;
      padding: 2px;
      font: 12px sans-serif;
      background: white;
      border: 0px;
      border-radius: 8px;
      pointer-events: none;
    }
    
    .cirle_animation {
      fill: none;
      stroke: red;
    }
    /* Legend Font Style */
    
    body {
      font: 11px sans-serif;
    }
    /* Legend Position Style */
    
    .legend {
      position: absolute;
      left: 800px;
      top: 350px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  v5
  <div id="circles" style="width:100%; height:100%x; border: 2px solid blue"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  
    CircleNumber = Math.round(15)
    const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 500).attr("height", 500);
    const data = Array.from(Array(CircleNumber).keys());

    function emananting() {
      var n = 0;
      points.selectAll('circle.emanting')
        .attr('r', 20)
        .style('opacity', 1)
        .transition()
        .each(function() { ++n; })
        .duration((d, i) => {
          return 5000;
        })
        .delay((d, i) => {
          return i * 1000;
        })
        .attr('r', 50)
        .style('opacity', 0)
        .on("end", function() { 
           if (!--n) emananting(); 
        }); 
    }
    
    const radialGradient = svg.append("defs")
      .append("radialGradient")
      .attr("id", "radial-gradient");

    radialGradient.append("stop")
      .attr("offset", "0%")
      .attr("stop-color", "#f4425f");

    radialGradient.append("stop")
      .attr("offset", "100%")
      .attr("stop-color", "orange");
    //background
    svg.append('rect')
      .classed('background', true)
      .attr('width', 500)
      .attr('height', 500)
      .attr('x', 0)
      .attr('y', 0)
      .attr('fill', 'black')
      .attr('opacity', 0.5);
    
    var masterData = d3.range(0,10).map(() => {
      return {
        x: Math.random() * 500,
        y: Math.random() * 500
      }; 
    });
    
    var points = svg.selectAll(".point")
      .data(masterData)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "point")
      .attr("transform", (d) => {
        return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")";
      });
    
    // Outer 
    points.append("circle")
      .classed('OuterCircle', true)
      .attr("r", 40)
      .attr("fill", "url(#radial-gradient)")
      .attr('gradient', () => {
        return
      })
      .attr("stroke", "orange")
      .on('mouseover', (d, i, g) => {
        d3.select(g[i]).transition().ease(d3.easeBounceOut).duration(500).attr("r", 60)
      })
      .on('mouseout', (d, i, g) => {
        d3.select(g[i]).transition().ease(d3.easeBounceOut).duration(500).attr("r", 40)
      });
      
    // Inner
    points.append('circle')
      .classed('InnerCircle', true)
      .attr('r', 20)
      .attr('stroke', 'yellow')
      .attr('fill', 'yellow')
      .attr('opacity', 1)
      .on('mouseover', (d, i, g) => {
        d3.select(g[i]).transition().ease(d3.easeBounceOut).duration(500).attr("r", 35)
      })
      .on('mouseout', (d, i, g) => {
        d3.select(g[i]).transition().ease(d3.easeBounceOut).duration(500).attr("r", 20)
      });

    points.selectAll('circle.emanting')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'emanting')
      .attr('id', (d, i) => {
        return 'number' + i;
      })
      .attr('r', 20)
      .attr('stroke', 'yellow')
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('opacity', 1)
      .attr('stroke-width', 2);

    emananting();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it's great! now the animation is infinite. and it was something I needed to solve, and I thank you, as always your answers are great. but my problem is in creating for two circles an animation of this type understanding that they are two instances of circles, with more circles doing the emananting effect..by the way, I use version 3, for me it was complicated to migrate from 5 to 3

Comment: @yavg, I updated my answer with example of how to add multiple data points using `d3` data joins.

Comment: thanks! I must translate this of v5 to v3. thank you!

Comment: @yavg, the only translation I think you need is that `.on("end", function() { ` becomes `.each("end", function() { `

Comment: is this line d3.select(g[i]).transition().ease(d3.easeBounceOut) in v3 to d3.select(this).transition().ease("bounce")  ? not works for me :(

Comment: is the best way mark?         d3.select(d3.selectAll(".InnerCircle")[0][i]).transition().ease("bounce").duration(500).attr("r", 35)